# Обобщающие и неопределённые местоимения в русском языке

Tags: грамматика

Здравствуйте! Столкнулся с таким явлением, что в современном английском языке с обобщающими и неопределёнными местоимениями такими, как "каждый" и "кто-нибудь", используется личное местоимение "они". У меня возник вопрос, есть ли такая же тенденция в современном русском языке или это будет считаться ошибкой? Вот, например, толкование на английском слова "offend" из авторитетного словаря "Collins Cobuild" и дословный перевод на русский:
If you offend SOMEONE, you say or do something rude which upsets or embarrasses THEM.
Если вы обижаете КОГО-НИБУДЬ, вы говорите или делаете что-нибудь грубое, что огорчает или смущает ИХ.
Я специально выделил, как английские, так и русские, неопределённое местоимение и местоимение "они", т. к. по-русски, на мой взгляд, было бы правильно сказать "... смущает ЕГО". Раньше в английском языке тоже было принято использовать в этом случае местоимение "он", но сейчас норма "они", что подтверждают авторитетные словари, в том числе и Оксфордский. Это связано с тем, что такие обобщающие и неопределённые местоимения не называют пол человека, а местоимение "он" относит к мужскому полу, поэтому некоторым англоговорящим это не нравится. А как в русском языке с этим дело обстоит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В английском 'they/them' со значением единственного числа применяется не только к неопределённым местоимениям, но и к существительным единственного числа, используемым в контексте неопределённости пола. Наиболее типичное -  person (a man or a woman), но they/them в таких случаях может ссылаться и на такие слова, как the killer (неизвестный убийца), the unsub (неустановленный преступник), citizen (гражданин, гражданка), patient (пациент, пациентка) и многие другие. В русском языке прямого аналога этому нет, поэтому в подобных случаях неопределённости на существительное ссылаются местоимением *в единственном числе и мужском роде*; это, конечно же, относится и к переводам на русский.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь всё понятно!